# Cannot add foreign key constraint 4

Tags: mysql, innodb

Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`proba` (
  `key` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `value` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`key`, `value`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`zavisnost` (
  `key` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `value` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`key`, `value`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_zavisnost_proba1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`key`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`proba` (`value`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I don't understand why this error appears. Please someone help... Thanks in advance..

Comment: It's probably because `proba.value` is not a primary key and thus, cannot be referenced as a foreign key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To define a `foreign key` on a column its parent referenced field must be indexed.

As per documentation on `foreign key` constraints:

> REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name,...)

Define an `INDEX` on `value` in table `proba` and it should be working.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`proba` (
  `key` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `value` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,

  KEY ( `value` ), -- <-------- this line was missing

  PRIMARY KEY (`key`, `value`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Once you define a `KEY` on the parent column, a foreign key column in `zavisnost` table can refer it, like.

```
...
FOREIGN KEY (`key`)
REFERENCES `mydb`.`proba` (`value`)
...
```

**Refer to**:

- [**MySQL Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

> [CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
>       [index_name] (index_col_name, ...)
>       REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
>       [ON DELETE reference_option]
>       [ON UPDATE reference_option]
>
> reference_option:
>       RESTRICT | CASCADE | SET NULL | NO ACTION